# Firebase Anonymous Authentication で User UID に有効期限はありますか？

Tags: firebase

Firebase の Anonymous Authentication を使ってみました。

console の Authentication / Users を見ると、下図の `(2)` で anonymous user に `User UID` が割り振られていました。

[image: User UID]

anonymous authentication において、この User UID は故意に削除しない限り、有効期限無く保持できるのでしょうか？

それとも有効期限があるのでしょうか？

ちなみに、User UID を手動で消して (delete account)、同じ端末で再度 anonymous authentication を試すと、前とは異なる User UID になりました。

Comment: 匿名アカウントには[有効期限がない](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48776702/3240599)ので、そのUIDも手を加えなければそのまま残ります。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。

その情報は firebase のドキュメントにも書かれているのでしょうか？

読んでみましたが、すぐには見つけ出せなかったのです。

Comment: 私が探した範囲では見つかりませんね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

私も探し出せませんでした。そもそもドキュメントが読みにくくて結構困ってしまいます。

sei0o さん、対応ありがとうございました。